# In Windows 7 how to select network profile for internet access?

Tags: windows-7, networking, internet-connection, network-adapter, network-profiles

At our office, the ADSL modem broke down, so I enabled WiFi access point on my smartphone to connect to internet that way. It works, but only if I disable the regular LAN, i.e. disable the network adapter that the computer uses to access the LAN.

I can see in Network and Sharing center that there are two network profiles, one for the LAN and one for the smartphone. The smartphone profile's network map shows that it has internet access, but the LAN profile's network map shows that there is no internet access. As expected.

I would have preferred to keep the LAN profile enabled to access the network disks as well as the internet (via the smartphone), but I can't get anything to connect to the internet as long as the LAN profile is enabled.

Is there any way I can tell Windows and/or applications to use the smartphone profile for internet access instead of the LAN, without completely disabling the LAN profile?

Comment: Give details of the computer (make, model) so we can have faintest idea... However, first check this: http://superuser.com/questions/479654/how-to-use-wireless-and-wired-connection-both-at-a-same-time-in-windows-7

Comment: It's a home built computer with a single Intel LAN adapter and no wireless. Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit. Smartphone is HTC One M8 connected with a USB cable. The HTC appears as a network adapter in Windows and an associated network profile with a working internet connection.

Comment: I thought this would be something generic in Windows, since the problem seems to be that Windows routes all internet traffic to the network associated with the wired LAN adapter even though that LAN has no working internet access, at the same time ignoring the other (HTC/USB) network profile which DOES have working internet access. How to force Windows to route internet traffic to the network profile that actually has a working internet connection?

Comment: You're right, this (as I re-read the question) is generic issue in WIndows, since I know smartphone connects over USB... You have to either bridge connections or assign metrics to networks: Solution 1: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/create-network-bridge#1TC=windows-7  Solution 2: http://www.speedguide.net/faq/how-to-tell-windows-7-to-use-a-different-default-350