# Prevent Windows Explorer going to Computer when network lost

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-explorer

When I undock my work computer, network connection is temporarily lost, while Windows switches from LAN to wireless.

When this happens, all open folders (that are on the share) revert to `Computer`. 
When redocking, they do not go back to the original folder.

When this happens, Windows Explorer throws a warning for every affected folder with a message like:

> *Restoring Network Connections*
>
> -- An error occurred while reconnecting [drive letter]: to [\path\to\network\share]  ...

On reconnection I have to manually go over each folder and press `back`. And close all the dialog boxes.

Is there a way to improve on this behavior?

Partial solutions might include:

- Prevent Windows Explorer from reverting to Computer.
- Turn off (multiple) disconnect warnings.

Comment: The easiest way is to keep wifi active even when connected to LAN as [explained in this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1046116/714576)

Answer (score 0):

There's no surefire answer not knowing your network characteristics, but here are some things you can try. I cannot test this in Windows 7 but they should work as they do in Windows 10.

### Solution 1: Network Bridge

You can create a network bridge between your LAN and WIFI. However, if both connections run over the same router, it could cause packet loss as there will be 2 concurrent IP's assigned to your PC. It really depends how your hardware is configured.

- Go to `Control Panel _> Network and Internet -> Network and Sharing Center`.
- On the left, click on `change adapter settings`.
- Select both connections. Right click to see options. Click network bridge.
- Windows will automatically create a network bridge.

### Solution 2: Adjust LAN priority settings

Usually, Windows gives priority to the LAN connection. Here is how to disable that. Depending on your system, there might additionally be a BIOS switch disabling WLAN when an ethernet connection exists, you'll have to make sure to check on that.

> 1. Go to network and sharing center in control panel.
> 2. Select change adapter settings
> 3. Right click on your Ethernet device and select properties on popup menu.
> 4. In properties menu, click configure button.
> 5. When configure menu, select advanced tab.
> 6. In advanced menu, under property list, look for "Priority & Vlan" and select it.
> 7. Look in value list to the right and select disable toggle.
> 8. Click Ok, on your way back out of menus and wait 15 seconds until system updates new value.

Taken from [this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/284d42b5-25c1-4b12-a5f1-8689b9ec8ce7/enable-simultaneous-network-connections-wifi-amp-ethernet?forum=win10itpronetworking), which contains further possible solutions for Windows 10 users.

Furthermore, make sure that in `Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options\Edit Plan Settings` when you go to `Change advanced power settings`, there is no setting which allows down-powering of your WIFI module.