# Windows 10, how to connect to wifi and ethernet at the same time while on different respective networks

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, ethernet, home-networking

I'd like to connect a Windows 10 computer to two separate networks simultaneously using two different routers, one with its wifi (internet-connected) and another with ethernet (no internet).

Is there a way to make it work like that?
As further clarification, the picture below shows what I had in mind.

[image]

Comment: Why wouldn't it work? I do it all the time...

Comment: I connected the ethernet and suddenly the internet from the wifi dropped. Would there be an extra step that's required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a working solution, based on the info combined from this [source](https://windowsreport.com/windows-10-ignoring-interface-metric/) and two SE posts ([Post 1](https://superuser.com/a/1046116/741816), [Post 2](https://superuser.com/a/1301133/741816)).

Basically, to have two simultaneous networks, I connected the devices as shown in the original post, then manually set the "Automatic Metric" to a lower number for a higher priority. In this case, the Wifi was assigned a "2" and the Ethernet was assigned a "3".

To do so, I did the following (mostly reproduced from [source](https://windowsreport.com/windows-10-ignoring-interface-metric/)):

1. Press Windows + R
2. Type in Control.exe
3. In Control Panel, double-click Network & Internet
4. Click on Status.
5. Click on Change Adapter options
6. Right-click the wireless adapter
7. Select Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)
8. Click Properties
9. Switch to the General tab
10. Click Advanced
11. Go to the IP Settings tab
12. Click to clear the Automatic metric checkbox
13. In the Interface Metric field, enter **2**.
14. Then repeat the above with the wired ethernet adapter, and in its Interface Metric field, enter **3**.

Answer (score 0):

Dell bios: Enter bios settings > connection > wireless radio control > control WLAN radio to “OFF”. Apply changes > Exit

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).